# Эволюция значений слова "двор"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Друзья, поделитесь знаниями о старославянском слове "двор" и о том, как оно меняло свое значение вплоть до сегодняшнего дня.
Есть предположения научного толка?

Comment: Может, вы имели в виду этимологию?

Comment: Зачем предположения? Знание об этом слове зафиксировано в словарях.

Answer (score 4):

**Современное значение слова:**

1. ДВОР,  1. Участок земли при доме, огороженный забором или стенами зданий. Въехать во д. 2. Крестьянский дом со всеми хозяйственными постройками; отдельное крестьянское хозяйство. Деревня в триста дворов. 3. Помещение, постройка для скота, хозяйственного инвентаря и т.п. Скотный д.
2. ДВОР,  В монархических странах: монарх и приближённые к нему лица, составляющие его окружение. Царский д.

Двор и дверь — однокоренные слова, известные с 12 века, в их основе и.-е корень. Развитие значения слова ***двор*** осуществлялось **по смежности**.

Сначала это дом (он расположен за дверью), затем помещение для скота в крестьянском хозяйстве (тоже за дверью).

За дверью (воротами) — усадьба, двор с постройками, и теперь уже жилой дом — это часть двора. (Получается взаимная связь: сначала двор как часть дома, а потом  дом как часть двора).

Даже дворец — это сначала "дворик", главная, но меньшая по площади часть дворовой территории (ЕЦ — ум.-ласкат. суффикс), и только с 15 века дворец — это дом феодала.

Римский форум (площадь) —  двор, территория за городскими воротами.

И люди — тоже часть двора. Слово ***дворянин*** известно с конца 12 века (сначала — дворовые люди), но в 14 веке дворянин  — это уже владелец жалованной земли (двора).

В 16 веке появляется  двор князя, а  приближенные ко двору люди — придворные. Двор приобретает новое значение — окружение монарха.

Таки образом, мы видим развитие значение слова ***двор,*** соединяющего разные понятия: территория,  постройки на этой территории, а также  люди, имеющие к этому отношение.

(Материал для ответа взят из историко-этимологического словаря П.Я. Черных).